# format string in hex flow in python

Tags: python

I use windows 7, python 2.7.

I want to format string to hex.
e.g., if `string = '123456`
I have to convert to `\x12\x34\x56`

I have tried this but failed：

```
string = '123456'
b'\x%s\x%s\x%s' % string[0:2], string[2:4], string[4:6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bytearray.fromhex()` method:

```
>>> bytearray.fromhex('123456')
bytearray(b'\x124V') # which is the same as b'\x12\x34\x56'
```